# FBX Export issue with Animation

Tags: animation, .fbx

I am quiet a beginner in Blender. I use it to animate FPS arms and guns to be put into my Unity game. Now I have a .blend file which contains actions (animations) for double-barreled shotgun, I used Rigify to rig arms, so it has these custom bone shapes, and I rigged shotgun by myself. Bones are linked with vertex groups. I have several "Child Of" constraints between IK palm bones and some gun bones. At different keyframes there are different influences.

The issue is that when I export using FBX, the position of left and right arms is wrong. I first thought it is something with Unity constraints recognition. But I tried to export to Maya or even open exported FBX in Blender again, and it is the same result. Let me show you:

Image 1: Correct pose before FBX export.

[image: Correct pose before FBX export.]

Image 2: Wrong pose after FBX export/import.

[image: Wrong pose after FBX export/import.]

So the left hand is lower than it should be. And it affects all animations.

Also, there is an issue with right hand during reload. It should hold new rounds to be loaded, but it is also a little bit moved aside, though rounds position is correct.

Image 3: Action "Reload_Full" frame 185 before FBX Export.

[image: Action "Reload_Full" frame 185 before FBX Export]

Image 4: Action "Reload_Full" frame 185 after FBX Export.

[image: Action "Reload_Full" frame 185 after FBX Export.]

I have tried using different FBX Export settings, but always the same result.
I am attaching a link for .blend file if needed: [Blend File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1svfQ8Y8pADDZ89atvuMzFUAykOjdmpd4/view?usp=drive_link).

Comment: Does your rig stretches the arm when you pull the controllers away? This can cause issues when exporting, if the deformer bones are connected.

Comment: I moved shoulder so it does not stretch, but there is same result unfortunately, left hand is still below gun barrel.